# Is there an idiomatic file extension for Jinja templates?

Tags: python, templates, file-extension, jinja2

I need to programatically distinguish between Jinja template files, other template files (such as ERB), and template-less plain text files.

According to [Jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/):

> A Jinja template doesn’t need to have a specific extension: .html, .xml, or any other extension is just fine.

But what should I use when an explicit extension is required? `.py` is misleading, and any search including the words "jinja" and "extension" are badly searchwashed by discussion around [Jinja Extensions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/).

I could easily dictate a project-wide convention (`.jnj` or `.ja` come to mind) but this is for open source so I don't want to buck the trend if there's already established practice somewhere.

---

**EDIT 1:** Again, I understand that the Jinja project — purposefully — does not define a default file extension. I'm asking if there are any unofficial conventions that have emerged for circumstances where one is desired for some project-specific reason.

---

**EDIT 2:** Clarification: This is not for HTML content.

Comment: Side note for others who were found this while searching in the context of HTML: one thing to be careful about is that file extensions have consequences as far as HTML autoescapes are concerned. If you are loading macros for use in an HTML template, `{% import "whatever.html" as foo %}` will act unsurprisingly while `{% import "whatever.jinja" as foo %}` will lead autoescapes like `>` becoming `&gt;`. I suspect this is part of why a lot of Django and Flask users end up using `.html`.

Comment: @mirth23 could you elaborate on that? I works fine for me. HTML form the macro is added as working HTML to the template, although I am using `.html.j2` as extension for them all.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**2021 update:**: Jinja now officially recommends using the extension `.jinja`. See [docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#template-file-extension)

---

**2020 update:**
Things changed since I wrote this answer, `.jinja2` and `.j2` are trending.

---

Jinja Authors did not define a default extension. Most of Jinja template editors like [TextMate extension](https://github.com/ozan/textmate-jinja-templates), [Emacs extension](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/jinja2-mode), and [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) mention no default extension to enforce Jinja highlighting.

Django already had [a request for setting such a default extension](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2614), which ended up as a *wontfix* issue after some debate. I quote from the closing message:

> Filetype detection based on extension is flawed for the very reasons described in these comments, so you have to do some internal inspection, just like MIME type detection works.

I suggest that you should use your own since there is no common one.

Comment: You're right, I know they don't define a default (and that decision was made with care and thought) but my project requires an explicit extension - I'm asking if there are any unofficial conventions which have emerged (before simply choosing one arbitrarily).

Comment: as far as I know, there is one. Personally, I use `html`.

Comment: if it was there a common extension, developers will tend to implement it in editors since most of those editors  are developed by community

Comment: I am not working on a web project. Even if I was, `html` would not be appropriate as again, it does not distinguish between an HTML file *with* Jinja, and one *without* (which is what I need to do).

Comment: so I suggest use your own since there is no common one.

Comment: I use `.jinja2`, haha.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please refer to answer my @Migwell instead. `.jinja2` is pretty much what you should use.

Comment: @rrlamichhane you are confused .jinja2 became .jinja, check the official documentation.

Comment: @bigOther well in Pycharm for instance `.jinja` is not recognized but `.jinja2` is. Would you mind linking to the official documentation?

Comment: @rrlamichhane pycharm should follow the new standard by creators,  official documentation here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#template-file-extension

Comment: I still don't get why it's called jinja2 when the version number is now 3.x  Regardless, the docs say:

> As stated above, any file can be loaded as a template, regardless of file extension. Adding a .jinja extension, like user.html.jinja may make it easier for some IDEs or editor plugins, but is not required.

Answer (score 53):

Ansible uses the `.j2` extension.

I couldn't find a definitive documentation about that precise point but we see occurences of the `.j2` extension in many places of their documentation :

If you look for `.j2` in the following pages you'll see many occurences :

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html

This is the convention that I use for other projects as well, except django templates.

Comment: Sublime Text users may be interested to learn that it recognises the .j2 extension, and can, for example, detect that *.html.j2 is an HTML jinja template.  Very cool.

Comment: I use the other way round like template.j2.html. Thus it could be syntax highlighted by any editors, but still marked it as being a template.

Answer (score 27):

IntelliJ's PyCharm uses `.jinja2` as their pattern for recognizing Jinja2 templates. For that reason I use the same (and recommend others do so too)

[image: pycharm filetypes]

Comment: I don't see "Jinja 2 Template" or *.jinja2 in my list of file types. I'm running 2018.3 Community Edition with very few extensions/plugins. EDIT: I bet this is specific to Professional Edition: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-template-languages.html

Answer (score 19):

I wanted to add an additional answer in 2020, as recently the Jinja2 project decided to drop the '2' from the name... meaning it's now just "Jinja".

Ansible still uses `.j2` in a lot of documentation, but seeing as the official Jinja template engine documentation now recommends `.jinja` if you want to use something other than non-Jinja-specific file extensions (see [docs here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#template-file-extension), or [when the change was added](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/1083/files#diff-0f54a58b39617a700a0b750e7a8bf07eR60-R71)), I think people will start moving that way (and dropping the use of `.j2` or `.jinja2`).

Answer (score 13):

Just FYI - Johnride above mentioned about Ansible using `.j2` as their convention for template file which is correct, just pointing out the "best practices" documented they [have now put out](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html), which mentions:

> templates end in `.j2`

Answer (score 10):

I use `.html.jinja2`, `.js.jinja2`, `.css.jinja2` etc to indicate that (a) it's a Jinja2 template, and (b) will compile into a HTML, JS or CSS file. I like the `.j2` choice in Ansible, but IMO using `.jinja2` makes it easier for a new contributor to guess what templating language is being used.

For Flask users, since auto-escaping is nice to have:

```
def _select_jinja_autoescape(filename):
    """
    Returns `True` if autoescaping should be active for the given template name.
    """
    if filename is None:
        return False
    return filename.endswith(('.html', '.htm', '.xml', '.xhtml',
        '.html.jinja', '.html.jinja2', '.xml.jinja', '.xml.jinja2',
        '.xhtml.jinja', '.xhtml.jinja2'))

app.jinja_env.autoescape = _select_jinja_autoescape
```

Answer (score 2):

I use .jnj extension - and for syntax highlighting and for snippets in vim I just copied, renamed and tweaked settings for [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

When I need some settings for html (like commenting, tag balancing, indenting etc) in jinja template, I also have a function set a time ago to work with PHP and WordPress - it toggles to html and back to previous filetype:

```
let g:my_file_type = 0

function! ToggleFileType()
  if g:my_file_type == 0
      set ft=html
      let g:my_file_type = 1
  else
      filetype detect
      let g:my_file_type = 0
  endif
endfunction
```

And it is bound to F12 key with `nmap <silent> <F12>  :call ToggleFileType()<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on official webpage, file extension does not matter but for syntax highlighting some IDEs will work with `.jinja`.
This is also the case for latest Jinja 3.0 version.

> Template File Extension As stated above, any file can be loaded as a
> template, regardless of file extension. Adding a **.jinja** extension,
> like user.html.jinja may make it easier for some IDEs or editor
> plugins, but is not required. Autoescaping, introduced later, can be
> applied based on file extension, so you’ll need to take the extra
> suffix into account in that case.
>
> Another good heuristic for identifying templates is that they are in a
> templates folder, regardless of extension. This is a common layout for
> projects.

You can check latest version here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/

Answer (score 0):

> "i like other way: `*.j2.html` ... syntax highlight by any editor" 
> - @Andor at [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29590931/#comment99697163_40309871)

- In vscodium, i used extension `samuelcolvin.jinjahtml` ,
- which provides syntax highlighting for not just the html, but also for the embedded templates as well
- on saving a blank file (on os win 10) with language-mode as `jinja-html` shows extensions as `*.jinja;*.jinja2;*.j2;*.html.j2`.
- and likewise `*.xml.j2;*.xml.jinja;*.xml.jinja2` for `jinja-xml` (in-case u want to hint about use of xhtml)
- `j2` would be not informative enough, and as many have said above, now even contradictory as well

so, my choice too would be `.html.jinja` and `.xhtml.jina`